# Conditional function not working as intended postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

So I got this table on postgresql that people regularly update and the below function.

```
table

id integer

status integer

date date

on_hold boolean
```

What this function is supposed to do is to fill out the date column automatically whenever the status becomes 50 and also if it was null

Problem is that i do not want the date column to be filled when the on_hold boolean column is true.

I've tried setting up the function just by typing on_hold = true but then it somehow says it doesn't exist. When i use old. or new. it doesn't pass any error but it still updates the date.

How to get to the intended result which is to not update the date when on_hold is true

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_update()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

BEGIN               
if new.status = 50 
and new.date is null 
and (new.on_hold = false or old.on_hold = false) 
then new.date = now() + interval '90' day ;
end if;
 RETURN NEW;                                                                    
END;


$function$
;
~~~
```

Comment: What it onhold switched from (true to false), what if from (false to true). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=28ab880036d41f9faadf921c877e1d91 Actually the code works: If only does not fill the date column if new and old on_hold column is true

Comment: @S-Man If the on hold is true then it's not expected to fill the date. So on your 2nd case where on_hold turns to true, it's not expected.

Comment: In the fiddle I showed, that your code works imho. So, it is not clear, what needs to be changed or what is your problem.

Comment: @S-Man thanks for replying but UPDATE mytable SET status=50, on_hold = true WHERE id=2;  
-- false becomes true -> WORKS, EXPECTED? -- it should not work, the date should stay blank because the on_hold is true

Comment: Ok: false -> false: Nothing happens. true -> true: Nothing happens. true -> false: Nothing happens. Only false -> true: Date should be written. Right?

Comment: @S-Man erm if something has on_hold true > false and gets status 50 then date should be updated. the other way around, from false to true, it should stay null

Comment: But you wrote: "do not want the date column to be filled when the on_hold boolean column is true"

Comment: @S-Man yep, so in other words, when it's false, date should be updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198554/discussion-between-s-man-and-luffydude).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the condition to

```
and old.on_hold != true -- != true include false *AND NULL*
```

and maybe (if you do not want to change anything if status is 50 and becomes 50 again) add:

```
(new.status = 50 and old.status != 50)
```

Full function:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9f8a77ce2246ddc8478bb5accc67a6b4)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_update()
    RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN               
    if (new.status = 50 and old.status != 50)
           and new.the_date is null 
           and old.on_hold != true 
    then 
        new.the_date = now() + interval '90' day;
    end if;

    RETURN NEW;                                                                    
END;
$$;
```